# How do I use a #defined constant as the max field width in fscanf?

Tags: c, macros, scanf, c89

All of this is in C89, not C99.

I have a constant.

```
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 256
```

I want to use it as the max field width in fscanf, sort of like this.

```
fscanf(input, "%256s", name);
```

But I want to use the MAX_NAME_LEN instead of the literal 256 for sake of good style. I have tried all of

```
fscanf(input, "%MAX_NAME_LENs", name);

char* max_name_len_str = malloc(16 * sizeof *max_name_len_str);
sprintf(max_name_len_str, "%d", MAX_NAME_LEN);
fscanf(input, "%" max_name_len_str "s", name);
free(max_name_len_str);

//works with printf, but has different meaning in scanf
fscanf(input, "%*s", MAX_NAME_LEN, name);

fscanf(input, "%%ds", MAX_NAME_LEN, name);
```

without success.

```
char* nameFormat = malloc(16 * sizeof *nameFormat); //I assume I don't ever want more than 10^13 characters in a name
sprintf(nameFormat, "%s%ds", "%", MAX_NAME_LEN);
fscanf(input, nameFormat, name);
free(nameFormat);
```

does work, but is ungainly as all get out. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: @weather-vane Your deleted answer was off by 1.  size vs length issue.

Comment: @chux: it was missing a cast too: `(rsize_t)(MAX_NAME_LEN + 1)`, or better `sizeof(name)`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: your deleted answer is useful: `fscanf_s` is not C89, but it is obviously available on the most common non C99 compiler: MSVC.

Comment: agreed, it might be useful for others looking for the same answer.

Comment: [How to prevent `scanf()` causing a buffer overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621394/) recommends the 'ungainly as all get out' solution because it works, more or less regardless of how `MAX_NAME_LEN` expands.  Almost any other solution puts limits on the permissible/acceptable values (expansions) of `MAX_NAME_LEN`.  It depends on how general and robust you need the code to be.  If you only need it to work with your code at the moment, you can hack together a string with the macro value.  If you need a general solution, then you probably need the `sprintf()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1st simplification.

```
// Unlikely need to malloc short array
char nameFormat[16]; // I assume I don't ever want more than 10^13 characters  
sprintf(nameFormat, "%%%ds", MAX_NAME_LEN);  // %% prints a %
fscanf(input, nameFormat, name);
```

2nd offering  or better, use stringify [@DevilaN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44685953/2410359).
Note that the size of the buffer needs to be at least 1 more than the `"%s"` width.

```
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 256
#define MAX_NAME_LEN_STR "256"

char name[MAX_NAME_LEN + 1];
fscanf(input, "%" MAX_NAME_LEN_STR "s", name);
```

3rd, use `fgets()`  (my preference), Of course this reads a *line* and not a sequence of non-white-space characters.  This often does meet that higher level goal though.

```
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 256
char name[MAX_NAME_LEN + 2];
fgets(name, sizeof name, input);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this macro:

```
#define STRINGIFY(X) INDIRECT(X)
#define INDIRECT(X) #X
```

like this:

```
#define MAX 10
puts("%"STRINGIFY(MAX)"d");
```

which will print `%10d`.

In your case it would be

```
char name[MAX_NAME_LEN + 1];
fscanf(input, "%"STRINGIFY(MAX_NAME_LEN)"s", name);
```

The `#` in the macro stringifies (makes `"` around it) whatever is after it. So the macro must be the decimal number only.
The level of indirection is needed to expand `MAX_NAME_LEN` to `256`. `INDIRECT(MAX_NAME_LEN)` would expand to `"MAX_NAME_LEN"`.

Comment: Curious, is `#X` valid for C89?

Comment: @chux : Yes, `str(s)` and `xstr(s)` (defined in the same way as [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.3/cpp/Stringification.html)) are given as examples in section 6.8.3.5.

Comment: One sharp stick -- you need to ensure that `MAX_NAME_LEN` defines a literal number (it cannot be a calculation, so `#define MAX_NAME_LEN (255-2)` would not work).

Comment: Furthermore, `MAX_NAME_LEN` must be written in base 10: `0x100` will not work either, nor will `20L`...

Comment: Suggest showing `name[]` declaration like `name[MAX_NAME_LEN + 1];` as the +1 is important.

Comment: Yes, putting `()` around it constitutes a calculation... in my mind anyways :-).

Answer (score 0):

You will struggle with fscanf. I don't know better solution than proposed by you if you are bound with fscanf.

Personally I would switch to fgets like in this simple example:

```
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 25

int main()
{
        char string[MAX_NAME_LEN];
        fgets(string,MAX_NAME_LEN,stdin);

        printf("%s", string);

}
```

Comment: There is a perfectly valid solution posted in mch's answer.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar 2 issues to cope when switching to `fgets()` that are not mentioned/addressed here: A  `+ 2` buffer needed (`\n` and `\0`) and that `fgets()` saves white-space, unlike `"%s"`.

Answer (score 0):

As a reference, following is a `fscanf_s()` approach to prevent overflow as used by earlier version of [VS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ybhk9kc(v=vs.100).aspx) that did not attain C99 compliance. An additional **`unsigned`** argument  follows `name[]` indicator the size of the buffer.  This appears to apply to VS 2015 too.

```
char name[MAX_NAME_LEN + 1];
fscanf_s(input, "%s", name, (unsigned) sizeof name);
```

C11 includes `fscanf_s()` in its Annex K which is *normative*, for information only, so a compliant compiler need not implement it.  Yet in C11, it is specified as needing a **`rsize_t/size_t`** argument .

```
fscanf_s(input, "%s", name, sizeof name);
```

If input is more than 256 non-white-space characters, a matching failure occurs.  In this case, `fscanf()` return `EOF`.  I *think* the VS version does the same.  I *think* both will consume all the non-white-space in the stream, even if there is not enough room to store them all.

---

Either of these is a bit different than the below in that extra text is not read into `name[]`, so no buffer overflow.  Any extra text remains for the next input function call.  `fscanf()` returns 1.

```
fscanf(input, "%256s", name);
```